# Linear Algebra proof: $\operatorname{proj}_a(\operatorname{proj}_a(b)) = \operatorname{proj}_a(b)$

Tags: vector-spaces

How would I show the following?

$$\operatorname{proj}_a(\operatorname{proj}_a(b)) = \operatorname{proj}_a(b)$$

I subbed in the projection formula of $\dfrac{a\cdot b}{\|a\|^2}a$ but I did not get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{proj}_a b = \frac{a\cdot b}{\|a\|^2}a$$

$$\Rightarrow \text{proj}_a\left(\text{proj}_a b\right) = 
  \text{proj}_a\left(\frac{a\cdot b}{\|a\|^2}a\right) =
  \frac{a\cdot b}{\|a\|^2}\text{proj}_a(a) = 
  \frac{a\cdot b}{\|a\|^2}a =
  \text{proj}_a b$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way to characterise $\operatorname{proj}_a(b)$ is as follows.

We can uniquely write $b$ as $u + v$ where $u \in \operatorname{span}\{a\}$ and $v \in (\operatorname{span}\{a\})^{\perp}$; $u$ is called the projection of $b$ onto $a$ and we write $\operatorname{proj}_a(b) = u$.

Using this definition, the result is immediate as $\operatorname{proj}_a(b) = u + 0$ where $u \in \operatorname{span}\{a\}$ and $0 \in (\operatorname{span}\{a\})^{\perp}$, so $\operatorname{proj}_a(\operatorname{proj}_a(b)) = \operatorname{proj}_a(u + 0) = u = \operatorname{proj}_a(b)$.

More generally, given a subspace $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we can write $u$ uniquely as $v + w$ where $v \in V$ and $w \in V^{\perp}$. Then $v$ is called the projection of $u$ onto $V$ and we write $\operatorname{proj}_V(u) = v$. As before, $\operatorname{proj}_V(\operatorname{proj}_V(u)) = \operatorname{proj}_V(u)$.

Even more generally, one often defines a mapping $P$ to be a projection if it satisfies the property $P\circ P = P$. This is not always the case though. For example, the map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto x$ is often called a projection, but does not satisfy the aforementioned property as the domain and codomain are different.